# Bluetooth Stack for Windows

Tags: bluetooth

Can any one tell me where can I download "***CSR Harmony***" bluetooth stack software. I'm searching wildly for this software. Please can anyone tell me where to download it. My bluetooth dongle is useless without this software so please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSR Harmony is not free. You must make an account on CSR support website and request access. However this stack is for integrators, when you integrate their chips into your hardware products.

Comment: What according to you is the best Bluetooth software for common users at home. Broadcomm doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: There isn't a best Bluetooth stack, you should ask what is it the most popular BT driver stack? I guess MS Bluetooth stack. But it depends, my BT dongle that I am using on desktop was shipped with Sybase iAnyware, the BT module integrated in the laptop uses MS BT stack. You should follow the most common stacks on Windows: first MS second Broadcomm and so on. I think your CSR chip is supported by MS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841803/EN-US/#appliesto

Comment: Just one thing my bluetooth chip is CSR but they have given me a bluesoleil stack which does not work well on Windows 7 and MS Stack does not support all the functionality like A2DP. Can you suggest any specific one?

Comment: @Soham Dasgupta I guess you work for a company, and you develop a custom solution based on a CSR chip. In this case your company would have no problem in asking CSR Harmony from CSR support. The other stacks are MS BT stack, Broadcomm, BlueSoleil and Sybase iAnywhere Blue SDK. You could try iAnywhere to see if it meets your expectations.

Answer (score 4):

Here the link Drivers + Software: [Download](http://www.aziocorp.com/support/download/files/wireless/btd-v400/CSR_Harmony_2.zip)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @RedEyedMonster The link is a zip file. Do you want it base-64 encoded and pasted in as an answer?

Comment: Just as suggested above the link is already dead by now.